# AA issue toon shading blender internal render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, antialiasing, npr

Hi i'm trying to create a toon effect using the blender internal render. But  not matter what AA settings i use it comes with jagged edges like in the image. Do i miss a setting?

[image: AA problem]

Comment: Please include screenshots of some of your settings, or perhaps upload your .BLEND file entirely using [this tool](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I actually found it, DOH!. Somehow 'Full Oversampling' was disabled in the material options. Needs to be enabled. It now renders smooth lines. 
Thanks for your respons.